# Re-use URI in many angular UI-Router state

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I tried to re-use a url for several states with angular UI-Router.

I tried to do that :

```
.state('app.contracts', {
    url: '/contracts',
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
        if ($rootScope.isDistributor) {
            $state.go('app.contracts-distributor');
        } else if ($rootScope.isShop) {
            $state.go('app.contracts-shop');
        } else if ($rootScope.isVendor) {
            $state.go('app.contracts-vendor');
        }
    }
})
.state('app.contracts-distributor', {
    controller: 'ContractDistributorController',
    templateUrl: 'views/contracts/list-distributor.html'
})
.state('app.contracts-shop', {
    controller: 'ContractShopController',
    templateUrl: 'views/contracts/list-shop.html'
})
.state('app.contracts-vendor', {
    controller: 'ContractVendorController',
    templateUrl: 'views/contracts/list-vendor.html'
})
```

But when I try this I have an infinite loop.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jr5CAhCu0nZbIr0KkI6Q?p=preview)

Not sure about the concept, what is the real goal ... but it should work. This is the adjusted state (just to go somewhere on ELSE):

```
.state('app', { template: '<div ui-view=""></div>', })
.state('app.contracts', {
  url: '/contracts',
  controller: ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state) {

    if ($rootScope.isDistributor) {
      $state.go('app.contracts-distributor');
    } else if ($rootScope.isShop) {
      $state.go('app.contracts-shop');
    } else { // if ($rootScope.isVendor) {
      $state.go('app.contracts-vendor');
    }
  }]
})
```

*I used array controller notation and [ng-strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), just to avoid later issues with minification.* And assured, that parent state app has target **`ui-view=""`**

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jr5CAhCu0nZbIr0KkI6Q?p=preview)